# How to separate my routers for 2 files in express.js?

Tags: typescript

Why i got an a error for add some `protected` access modifier??
In case with `private` all its gona OK!

```
export interface IFighter {
    readonly _name: string;
    protected _health: number; // [ts] 'protected' modifier cannot appear on a type member.
    _power: number;
    health: () => number;
    name: () => string;
    setDamage: (damage: number) => void;
    hit: (enemy: Fighter, point: number) => void;
    knockout: () => Promise<any>;


}


export class Fighter implements IFighter { // Class 'Fighter' incorrectly implements interface 'IFighter'.
// Property '_health' is protected in type 'Fighter' but public in type 'IFighter'.
    _name: string;
     protected _health: number;
    _power: number;
  constructor(name: string, health: number, power: number) {
    this._name = name;
    this._health = health;
    this._power = power;
  }

  health(): number {
    return this._health;
  }

  name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  setDamage(damage: number): void {
    this._health = this._health - damage;
    console.log(`${this._name} got ${damage} dmg. ${this._health}hp less`);
  }

  hit(enemy: Fighter, point: number): void {
    let damage: number = point * this._power;
    enemy.setDamage(damage);
  }

  knockout(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("time is over");
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(() => {});
      }, 500);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base logic behind Interface is to act like a *Public Contract* or schema so we can use it on other objects, while maintaining certain amount of functionality or properties that are must.
In your case, **IFighter** is an Interface, hence, It cannot declare its properties as protected. Otherwise, it will lose the purpose of using an interface.

You should take off the protected from the interface and just declare it in the class itself.